Are Optional fields okay?
Some fields may be optional. That is, a value doesn't have to be ever assigned to it. Luckily, Java has a special null-safer type for optional values — Optional
However, if I try to make a field of type Optional, I get a warning. Here's how it goes

Reports any cases in which java.util.Optional, java.util.OptionalDouble, java.util.OptionalInt, java.util.OptionalLong, or com.google.common.base.Optional are used as types for fields or parameters.
Optional was designed to provide a limited mechanism for library method return types in which a clear way to represent "no result" was needed.
Using a field with the java.util.Optional type is also problematic if the class needs to be Serializable, as java.util.Optional is not serializable.

  class MyClass {
    Optional<String> name; // Optional field
  
    // Optional parameter
    void setName(String name) {
      this.name = Optional.ofNullable(name);
    }
  }

So whenever I have to reference that, I either have to perform null checks or wrap it in Optional each time. A maintainer may forget to do so one day, an NPE will be thrown
I don't care about Java's serialization. Is the advice of not using Optional fields still valid then? Why, if so?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547673/why-java-util-optional-is-not-serializable-how-to-serialize-the-object-with-suc

@Ewan it's irrelevant, sadly. It's not about serialization at all

why do you say its irrelevant?

The accepted answer to that question tells you why you get those warnings: the authors of Java think that Optional has a narrow use case, and should stick to it.

The question to ask is why do you want the field to be optional. If only to let you wait until later to provide a value, consider waiting until the value is available to instantiate the class.

@Ewan I wasn't clear enough. The first "it" referred to the question you suggested. The second "it" referred to this question

@chepner optional functionality relies on that value. But an instance of the class, a GUI element, may still live a happy life without that functionality. To be more precise, it's an XML key that references a node with settings — font family, style, size. If it's supplied, then persisted settings are applied. If not, that's fine too, defaults will get applied instead. Obviously, I don't want to pass any Fonts into the class's constructor, that's too specific. The settings may contain things beyond font

@SergeyZolotarev yes im asking why you think that answer isnt applicable to your problem. it seems pretty clear on the various issues with using Optional on classes. ie serialisation can be used in odd places, ie libs and remote execution and they will break with your class

@user20574 this is a non-argument, as non-nullable fields are already used and are enforced in runtime and/or design time.

Serialization argument is stupid, because  no object should be serializable in modern Java.

@user20574 use Objects.requireNonNull()

Whether something is "OK to use" depends on intent, team coding practices, common programming idioms, and how strictly you want to adhere to API guidelines.
First, the facts about Optional<T>:

A container object which may or may not contain a non-null value.
...
API Note:
Optional is primarily intended for use as a method return type where there is a clear need to represent "no result," and where using null is likely to cause errors. A variable whose type is Optional should never itself be null; it should always point to an Optional instance.

Source: Oracle Java 11 JDK documentation (emphasis, mine)
Not a lot of concrete guidance here beyond the recommendation that Optional<T> be used as a return type. In a strict sense, you are not using this as a return type, therefore the answer is "no, this is not OK." On the other hand, you are using it as the type for a field which may contain null. So you seem to satisfy the first part.
But it works.
That's why it's important to remember these are guidelines. The mechanics of whether you can use something are a different discussion, and hence, your question. Instead, I like to see how these optional fields are being used to ensure a more suitable OO design doesn't already exist.
If I had to look at a codebase that was peppered with field.ifPresent(foo -> foo.method()) every time field was used, I would start to wonder if we have a design problem with field rather than it's type. Even in cases where you have field.isPresentOrElse(foo -> foo.method(), () -> something else), I still think we are missing something. Frankly, the constant calls to the Optional<T> methods as a round-about way to avoid NullPointerExceptions makes me think the Null Object Pattern might be a better choice here. Every method in the "null object" can be a no-op. Getters can return pre-canned values (whatever the "or else" part of Optional.ifPresentOrElse() would have returned).
I don' like optional dependencies because they can be null, so now I need to incessantly check for null, or I need to use some other non-idiomatic construct like Optional<T> with a bunch of pass-through method calls in lieu of null-checks.
Code is much cleaner if you can simply call field.method() rather than field.ifPresent(foo -> foo.method()).
Some additional notes:

The guidance in this answer applies best to situations where the T is a complex type. When T is a string, boolean, or numeric type, then the "optional" part of an Optional<T> becomes meaningful. An Optional<boolean> can be true, false, or not present, which your application could interpret as "not specified." In that case, document this fact on the field.

In the case of a String, consider defaulting to an empty string instead. No need for null if you have proper encapsulation. A constructor or setter can enforce the "empty string instead of null" constraint.


When T is a complex type, consider other, more straight-forward designs first before resorting to an Optional<T>, if for no other reason than the Principle of Least Astonishment.

Choose code that is easy to read first. In situations like this, I like to write the same code multiple ways. Consider writing it when checking for nulls, using another more suitable design pattern (like Null Object Pattern), and using an optional. Same code. 3 different styles. Which one do you like?

And then present the same 3 styles to a colleague to see which one they like.



In the end, you get working code either way. Personal taste, other object-oriented design practices and team habits play a bigger role in this decision than API guidance.

A failure to use Null Object is on author and is not a problem with Optional. Optional turns mandatory (non-Null in any shape) field into an optional field. Complexity of type is not relevant, only a presence of a suitable default value is. Principle of Least Astonishment requires use of Optional, because of its well-defined semantics. There is no way to get astonished with Optional.

@Basilevs, I both agree and disagree, depending on the circumstance. Especially read the bulleted list at the bottom of my answer under "Some additional notes". I don't think this is a case where it is always OK, so use it without thinking through your design first. That is the whole point of my answer. The OP doesn't give us a lot of examples for how they are using it, so my answer might be a bit more generalized than the others.

I'm not sure on which point do you disagree. It is fine to thoughtfully design complex things, but Optional is not complex.  Could you provide an example where both Null Object and Optional are ill suited? (and where memory consumption is not critical)

@Basilevs: you need to look at the code to make that judgement. You can get things to work either way, but how does the code look? That matters too, and just because you can use a language feature doesn't mean your teammates will like it. A good portion of this question comes down to a matter of taste. Again, read the bullet list at the bottom of my answer.

Give me the code then. I've reread the bullet points and still fail to see how would Optioanal be worse than null.

Optional is now intended to be used as a Monad. Java designers effectively admitted that by adding Optional.stream() method.
Ignore earlier discussions about:

serialization. Serialization should not be used in new code
library interfaces. They are not different from your own.
method argument. Using Optional as argument in much more idiomatic than doing a conditional dispatch over method overloads.

Surprisingly, important reasons not to use an Optional as a field are:

memory consumption - it increases the size of your field up to 4 times.
performance - it introduces additional memory indirection

These are only applicable to long-lived numerous objects (example: gamedev).

Is that a valid enough reason, in your opinion? It's still likely going to be negligible

@SergeyZolotarev it is only valid in a special case of large object count. This happens in data processing or gamedev, for example.

Whether or not to use Optional<T> as a field depends on what your class is. Think hard about what you're trying to represent.
If your class is meant to represent a person, should the name field be Optional<String>? The answer to that question is entirely about the specific business logic of your application. Maybe a name-less person doesn't make sense in your application and so every Person should have a name. Maybe your application needs to be able to represent a truly nameless person. Or maybe a person who has a name but whose name is not known. Maybe you don't care about that last distinction.
Ultimately this is Java so unless you carefully craft your constructor and ideally have no setters, everything is potentially null anyway. However, using Optional<T> as a way to communicate your intent that the field is truly meant to be sometimes absent is much better than silently allowing null. Future maintainers will thank you for being explicit.

The question is talking about optional fields. Why use name as an example? Mandatory fields are not optional, duh.

Perhaps you should read this essay: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Optional is meant as a parameter passing mechanism, not a data storage mechanism.
So you put Optional as the argument type for the setter, then use its methods to determine whether to actually set the field. And in the getter you would create another Optional and fill it depending on whether the field was set or not. Obviously in this very narrow usecase it makes little sense, just initialise the field to null in the constructor (or in the field definition), but that's how Optional is meant to be used.
You'd need to initialise the Optional anyway in a constructor in order to be able to return it in the getter, so why bother with an Optional at all in this specific usecase?

I want to wrap a nullable value in an Optional one time instead of N times where N is the number of references to that value

@SergeyZolotarev that's not how Optional was intended to be used. Sure you can do it, but you're going to get warnings and no doubt code review tools like Sonar are going to complain as well.

The question is why?

Optional types are used to make partial functions total, so that the function can return something when it's not defined for a particular argument, rather than raising an exception. A class with an optional attribute, though, can be split into two classes, and you choose which to instantiate based on what you need. You don't have to go to such extremes, which is why you're just getting a warning rather than an error.

@chepner so you reject the idea of injectable Strategy because, the class can be made abstract and a strategy method could be overridden? Ridiculous.

I never said I rejected anything, though I fail to see how allowing optional types is necessary to the Strategy pattern.

But you did, by insisting that optional data has to be extracted to a separate class. This is a direct analogy to a strategy pattern, where customization is either injected or provided via inheritance.

I insisted nothing. I said you could do that, not that you must do that.

Why on Earth has this answer gotten so many down-votes? Oracle literally says that Optionals are meant to be return values: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html

@GregBurghardt beats me, guess people don't like to hear things they don't like and take it out on the person telling them rather than the source of the information...

@GregBurghardt why does this answer talk about parameters then?

@Basilevs, because that was the original intent of Optionals. It might not be the current use, though.

Return value is not a parameter
